# Swap indexes using slices?

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, slice, swap

I know that you can swap 2 single indexes in Python

```
r = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'] 
r[2], r[4] = r[4], r[2]
```

output:

```
['1', '2', '5', '4', '3', '6', '7', '8']
```

But why can't you swap 2 slices of indexes in python?

```
r = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

I want to swap the numbers 3 + 4 with 5 + 6 + 7 in r:

```
r[2:4], r[4:7] = r[4:7], r[2:4]
```

output:

```
['1', '2', '5', '6', '3', '4', '7', '8']
```

expected output:

```
['1', '2', '5', '6', '7', '3', '4', '8']
```

What did I wrong?
output:

Comment: Looks like you just have an off-by-one error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slicing is working as it should. You are replacing slices of different lengths. `r[2:4]` is two items, and `r[4:7]` is three items.

```
>>> r = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
>>> r[2:4]
['3', '4']
>>> r[4:7]
['5', '6', '7']
```

So when `['3', '4']` is replaced, it can only fit `['5', '6']`, and when `['5', '6', '7']` is replaced, it only gets `['3', '4']`. So you have `['1', '2',`, then the next two elements are the first two elements from `['5', '6', '7']` which is just `['5', '6'`, then the two elements from `['3', '4'` go next, then the remaining `'7', '8']`.

If you want to replace the slices, you have to start slices at the right places and allocate an appropriate size in the array for each slice:

```
>>> r = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
>>> r[2:5], r[5:7] = r[4:7], r[2:4]
>>> r
['1', '2', '5', '6', '7', '3', '4', '8']
 old index: 4    5    6    2    3
 new index: 2    3    4    5    6
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought swapping inserts the slices in the list. I want to create a function where to indicate the slices to swap, but if I read your answer it is not possible.

Comment: @Reman what type of function have you envisioned? Do you have a rough sketch? Although I think it would be better to ask that in a separate question altogether.

Comment: @Reman I think it should be a separate question altogether and not an edit in this one.

Comment: @AKS, ok http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953810/swap-slices-of-indexes-using-a-function

Answer (score 1):

Think of this:

```
r[2:4], r[4:7] = r[4:7], r[2:4]
```

as similar to this:

```
original_r = list(r)
r[2:4] = original_r[4:7]
r[4:7] = original_r[2:4]
```

So, by the time it gets to the third line of that, the 4th element isn't what you think it is anymore... You replaced `'3', '4'` with `'5', '6', '7'`, and now the `[4:7]` slice starts with that `'7'`.

Comment: Unpacking assignment actually works in-place, e.g. `a=1; b=2; a,b = b, a+b` having a different result from `a=1; b=2; a = b; b = a+b`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> r = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
>>> r[2:5], r[5:7] = r[4:7], r[2:4]
>>> r
['1', '2', '5', '6', '7', '3', '4', '8']
```

In your code:

```
>>> r[2:4], r[4:7] = r[4:7], r[2:4]
```

You are assigning `r[4:7]` which have 3 elements to `r[2:4]` which have only 2.

In the code I posted:

```
>>> >>> r[2:5], r[5:7] = r[4:7], r[2:4]
```

`r[4:7]` which is `['5', '6', '7']`, replaces
`r[2:5]` which is `['3', '4', '5']`

`r` resulting in `['1', '2', '5', '6', '7', '6', '7', '8']`

and then:

`r[2:4]` which was `['3', '4']`, replaces
`r[5:7]` which is `['6', '7']`

So final result being:

```
['1', '2', '5', '6', '7', '3', '4', '8']
```