# Swap slices of indexes using a function

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, indexing, swap

Follow-up question of:
[Python swap indexes using slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36952565/python-swap-indexes-using-slices/36952734?noredirect=1#comment61465232_36952734)

```
r = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

If I want to swap slices, using a function, what would be the correct method?

```
def swap(from,to):
  r[a:b+1], r[c+1:d] = r[c:d], r[a:b]

swap(a:b,c:d)
```

I want to swap the numbers 3 + 4 with 5 + 6 + 7 in r:

```
swap(2:4,4:7)
```

Is this correct?

Comment: It should work if done properly, ie without all those syntax errors (`from` can't be used as a variable name, and `2:4,4:7` is not how you slice)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without any calculation, you can do :

```
def swap(r,a,b,c,d):
   assert a<=b<=c<=d  
   r[a:d]=r[c:d]+r[b:c]+r[a:b]
```

Comment: Nice, straightforward, effective approach.

Comment: If the question had just been "how do I swap sections of a list?" I would've done something like `return r[:a] + r[c:d] + r[b:c] + r[a:b] + r[d:]`, but I got stuck with the slice assignment unpacking. This answer combines the simple approach with a memory-saving in-place slice assignment for what's probably the optimal combination of efficiency and simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting (but silly one, the one by B. M. is clearly better) solution would be to create an object that supports slicing:

```python
class _Swapper(object):
    def __init__(self, li):
        self.list = li

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        x = list(item)
        assert len(x) == 2 and all(isinstance(i) for i in x)
        self.list[x[0]], self.list[x[1]] = self.list[x[1]], self.list[x[0]]

def swap(li):
    return _Swapper(li)

swap(r)[a:b, c:d]
```